# How can I get redux option to determine how many sidebars are registered?

Tags: wordpress, frameworks, meta

Is it possible to get a redux theme options and use the value in theme functions to determine how many sidebars are registered?

I tried using the method i'd use in a template to get an option which was

```
global $redux_demo;

$footer_sidebars = $redux_demo['opt-select-footercol'];

register_sidebars($footer_sidebars, array('name'=>'Sidebar %d'));
```

Answer (score 1):

In your redux.php in sidebar section (If you created it), you could add an array:

```
array(
    'id'        => 'opt-select-footercol',
    'type'      => 'select',
    'data'      => 'sidebars',
    'title'     => __('Sidebar', 'redux-framework-demo'),
    'desc'      => __('Choose the sidebar you wish to appear.', 'redux-framework-demo'),
),
```

And in your page you should be able to add it with

```
<?php if(isset($redux_demo['opt-select-footercol'])): ?>
  <?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar($redux_demo['opt-select-footercol']) ) : ?>
    <div class="widget">
        <h3><?php _e('Search', 'redux-framework-demo'); ?></h3>
        <?php get_search_form(); ?>
    </div>
  <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif;?>
```

The first part should list all registered sidebars, and with the second code you can display the one you choose.

Comment: Hey thanks for the help but I wanted something like if 4 col selected register 4sidebars if 3 register 3 sidebars

Comment: You mean in footer? Then you'd need to edit the footer.php, or whatever file your footer widgets are located. And It would mean creating a few if clauses to check how many widgets there are and then putting them into certain spans.